# Zoomin and Blur the image in css With responsive to all Browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

While clicking an image, the image should zoom in and set as background for the page with blurred property.

I tried with the following code,..

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
position: absolute;
margin-left: 100px;
right: 0;
 z-index: 99999;
  display: block;
  background: url(music_album_img/images8.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  -webkit-filter: blur(75px);
  -moz-filter: blur(50px);
  -o-filter: blur(75px);
  -ms-filter: blur(75px);
  filter: blur(75px);
}
```

Here i set the image with 100% of Width and Height.

```
 .mi {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#background-image, #background-image span { 
    background: #fff url(http://css-plus.com/examples/2012/03/gaussian-blur/i/fence-sprite.png) no-repeat left top; 
    height: 220px; 
    width: 320px; 
    position: relative;
}
#background-image span { 
    background-position: 0 -220px; 
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out; 
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out; 
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out; 
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out; 
          transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
           opacity: 1;

}
#background-image:hover span { opacity: 1; }
```

The selected image haven't set as background and no property have set on Blurring.

I have used this [link](http://codepen.io/aniketpant/pen/DsEve). It only works on Chrome and Opera, not for other common browsers...

Give some suggestions on it

Comment: We cant set an image with blurred content using css...

Comment: We can set it up, i want to set the image dynamically and responsive for all the browsers

Comment: Not supported in IE. http://caniuse.com/css-filters

Answer (score 0):

i'm very happy to share this solution with you all..

I tried the following code for filter option in firefox to get the solution

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'effect-blur-1\'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=\'15\' /></filter></svg>#effect-blur-1");
```

You can find the solution [here.](http://codepen.io/beben-koben/pen/uHrdi)

But still searching for the solution in IE, and for Safari blur option will work on Safari6.0 or Later. But Unfortunately Safari for Windows has been discontinued. The most recent Safari version you can get is 5.1.7.